# Solve this indefinite integral: $\int \frac{x+2}{x^2-1}dx$

Tags: integration

I need to solve this indefinite integral: $$\int \frac{x+2}{x^2-1}dx$$

but the result is wrong.

Here my steps:

$D° > N° $ so I need to reduce the Denominator, which is a difference of two square: $(x^2-1) = (x-1)(x+1)$ so my new integral is:

$$ \int \frac{x+2}{x^2-1}dx = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+1} = \frac{A(x+1)+B(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x = Ax+Bx \\
2 = A-B
\end{cases}
$$
and I get:
\begin{cases}
A= \frac{1}{2}\\
B = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}

So:

$$\int \frac{x+2}{x^2-1}dx = \int \frac{1}{2(x-1)}dx -\int \frac{1}{2(x+1)}dx$$
I need to get the derivate of the denominator
$$\int \frac{x+2}{x^2-1}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2}{2(x-1)}dx - \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2}{2(x+1)}dx$$

So I get:

$$\frac{1}{2}ln|2x-2| - \frac{1}{2}ln|2x+2| + C$$

but the result is wrong: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Cfrac%7Bx%2B2%7D%7Bx%5E2-1%7Ddx

Comment: You can simplify by just dragging the factors $A,B$ in front of the integrals (besides using $A=3/2).$ This eliminates the superfluous $2$ inside the logarithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake with your partial fractions:

$A$ should be $\frac{3}{2}$

$$ \frac{x+2}{x^2 -1} =  \frac{x+2}{(x -1)(x+1)} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+1}$$

Eliminate A and B in turns by making $x+1=0$ or $x-1=0$

$$ x+2 \equiv A(x+1) + B(x-1)$$

let $x=1$

$$ A = \frac{3}{2}$$

let $x= -1$

$$ B = -\frac{1}{2}$$

$$  \frac{x+2}{x^2 -1}  = \frac{3}{2(x-1)} - \frac{1}{2(x+1)}$$

You can then integrate the above which is very straight forward

Answer (score 2):

$$\int {x+2\over x^2-1}dx={1\over 2}\int {d(x^2)\over x^2-1}+2\int {dx\over x^2-1}$$
Now apply standard integration formulae..

Comment: Good answer, but check your signs.

Comment: @GFauxPas Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{x+2}{x^2-1}\ dx=\int \frac{(x+1)+1}{(x-1)(x+1)}\ dx=\int \frac{1}{x-1}\ dx+\int \frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}\ dx\ ?
\end{equation}